# Showing routes in maps

Tags: 7, google-maps

I have a collection of points (latitude/longitude) that i would like to represent on a Map as route. Is there a module that permits this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny you should say that. I just fixed a bug in leaflet module that was preventing me from showing linestrings (i.e. a route).

There are other ways of doing this but this is a good efficient way and leaflet maps are beautiful!

1. Install the patched version (i.e. the latest and greatest version) of leaflet module - http://drupal.org/node/1707882
2. Apply the tiny change I put here - http://drupal.org/node/1667780
3. Install http://drupal.org/project/geofield (7-1.x-dev version) and http://drupal.org/project/geophp
4. Install http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps to get a whole bunch of ready made tiles.
5. Add a field to your node using geofield with WKT format.
6. Add a node with your points using the WKT linestring format for your route = LINESTRING(lon lat, lon lat, lon lat)
7. Change the display format for the field to leaflet and choose which map style you want.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text

http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/

Add a comment here if you get stuck at any point.